# Cache an Akka Substream source and reuse it?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is it possible to cache a source and reuse it without triggering "Substream cannot be materialized more than once"?

I'm doing a stream join which requires a call out to a microservice for each element on the left. That call returns a stream of records to join to. I want to cache the source so that the same calls to the microservice result in the cached stream. But the flatMapConcat I'm doing throws the "Substream cannot be materialized more than once" error. The code looks like this:

```scala
    val cache = new util.HashMap[AnyRef, Source[Array[AnyRef], Any]]()

    inputSource
        .flatMapConcat { record =>
          val key = leftKey(record)
          val rightElemSource = if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
            cache.get(key)
          } else {
            val rightElemSourceInner = doSomethingToGetSource()
            cache.put(key, rightElemSourceInner)
            rightElemSourceInner
          }

          rightElemSource.map(join(record, _))
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Source` represents a potentially huge or even infinite stream of data. It's designed to be traversed only once like `Iterator`. If you really want the content of the source to be reused you have to collect it into a regular data structure, say, `Seq`.
So your cache would be of type `util.HashMap[AnyRef, Seq[Array[AnyRef], Any]]`.

Comment: That's what I ended up using, but it meant using an execution context and materializer from within the flatMapConcat call, then doing a mapAsync. I'm not sure what the performance implications of that are. I'm using the play framework and I just passed the execution context from the controller

Comment: Can't help you here. Don't have any experience with play and have limited and not very positive experience with akka. I guess the execution context from the controller is a fixed-size pool (optimized for cpu-bounded tasks) so it shouldn't be used for remote calls.